# How to get all values from a list of dict that matches key prefix?

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I have a list of dictionaries, for example:

```
[
 {
  'id': '11110110011',
  'a_dept_performance': 3,
  'a_group_performance': 2,
  'a_user_performance': 3,
  'f_service': 4,
  'f_facility_service': 2,
  'k_helpful': 2
  ...
 },
 {
  'id': '11110110012',
  'a_dept_performance': 3,
  'a_group_performance': 3,
  'a_user_performance': 3,
  'f_service': 2,
  'f_facility_service': 3,
  'k_helpful': 2
  ...
 },
 ...
]
```

I want to retrieve all value that matches with a specific prefix, like:

```
a_ = [3, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, ...]
f_ = [4, 2, 2, 3, ...]
k_ = [2, 2, ...]
```

Any way to implement this? My data is big, so I'm wondering if there's a faster way to do it.

Comment: *I'm wondering if there's a faster way to do it* - faster than what? You didn't show your efforts...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't say if there is a faster way to do this, but perhaps you should think of changing your data structure if your data is large. Your setup does not seem like a particularly efficient or intuitive method to store your data.

Consider a database, or if you want to stay within Python, look at Pandas.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion, I'm changing my data structure to Pandas Datatable and manage to do it.

Answer (score 1):

you can use `collections.defaultdict` to store your values:

```
from collections import defaultdict

my_prefixes = {'a_', 'f_', 'k_'}
result = defaultdict(list)
for d in my_list:
    for k, v in d.items():
        if k[:2] in my_prefixes:
            result[k[:2]].append(v)
print(result)
```

**output:**

```
defaultdict(<class 'list'>, {'a_': [3, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3], 'f_': [4, 2, 2, 3], 'k_': [2, 2]})
```

if you know that  all the key are the same for every dictionary you can bring a plus of speed as @golf_cy was mentioned:

```
from collections import defaultdict
my_prefixes = {'a_' : ['a_dept_performance', 'a_group_performance'],
               'f_': ['f_service', 'f_facility_service'],
               'k_': ['k_helpful']}

result = defaultdict(list)
for d in my_list:
    for k, v in my_prefixes.items():
        result[k].extend([d[e] for e in v])
```

Comment: the time complexity is O(n*m), practically every key is iterated one time, why should be slow?

Comment: a set of keys? why I do that? you  have to check each key if is from the wanted prefixes, I can't see a better way, you have to iterate over each key to check  them

Comment: can't figure out your suggestion, you may bring your answer and check?

Comment: @gold_cy you want to say that all key are the same? so we can simplify base on this assumption? yes sure, but the OP didn't mention that

Comment: The only improvement i can see is indeed remove the `if` check because as it seems OP just want the values **according** to the prefix, so you don't actually need to check for a set of pre-defined prefixes. But that's just my take on it...

Comment: Regarding the second version, it is still basically the same. You still iterate the same amount of times, as you said in previous comments you have to check all keys in the end. And it is less readable in my opinion...

Comment: I think OP has to say if all the dictionaries have the same keys or not

Comment: if we know the  keys then  the time complexity can be O(n * k), where k is the number of total keys in a dict  that we want and `k <= m`, where m is the  total number of keys in a dict, so the second version is more efficient, but again, OP has to clarify